# Reuse bootstrap class name for my own styles?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So for example I have a `navbar` as following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    ...
</nav>
```

Is it ok to reuse the `navbar` class in my own `css` files, or should I declare a new name, like `mynav_main` to avoid potential conflict? Is there a definitive rule or it depends on the situation? I don't want my html to be bloated but there might be something I'm missing here.

Comment: it is okay, for sure. I'm not remembering where but Im sure I've seen official documentation to this effect. if I find it Ill post an answer

Comment: You can overwrite Bootstrap's `css` using their own class, but you must use the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) that Bootstrap uses to properly overwrite it

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap's styles at the same time as your own, and you use the same class name in your stylesheet, then yes you run the risk of conflict, but it depends on how you use it exactly.

Comment: You sure can use the same naming conventions; nothing is stopping you :) Just be aware that your elements will inherit all of the rules applied to the Bootstrap elements. This could help/hinder you depending on your desired display ;)

Answer (score 0):

first, you might check here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ if you want to generate customized css for selectors bootstrap provides. this way, you won't have to compete with bootstrap's specificity.

second, you will have to improve specificity (such as using !important if the rule you write doesnt seem to stick, however, bootstrap has at times used this itself)

while there is no text specifically advising to override on getbootsrap.com (like I hoped, must have been a dev comment somewhere), there is certianly plenty of uses of the word in the documentation, showcasing at least an acknowledgement of the necessity of such a practice in generating bootstrap itself or changing it over time.